# Inverse of dopamine reuptake inhibitor?

Tags: neuroscience, pharmacology, neurotransmitter

The wikipedia article on the [dopamine transporter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopamine_transporter) gives examples of some drugs whose effects are mediated by the inhibition of the dopamine transporter, such as cocaine and amphetamines.  Are there any drugs or substances whose mechanism of action involves increasing the activity of the dopamine transporter, i.e., a "DAT releaser?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to note the difference in mechanism between cocaine and meth. While cocaine blocks reuptake, meth makes VMAT - vesicular monoamine transport - leaky and actually reverses the transportation of dopamine, so that instead of transporting dopamine into the axon terminal, it actually transports dopamine out as it leaks from the vesicle that carry it. This is what is meant when referring to 'reverse transport' of dopamine through DAT. Feel free to read this abstract and the sources it cites (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2631950/).

Regarding the possibility of a DAT agonist of sorts, looks like current research has identified some potential targets. One of which seems to be luteolin and its derivatives (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20971650). Current studies find new derivatives and test the EC50 to assess pharmacological efficacy.

Answer (score 0):

Amphetamine isn't a DAT inhibitor. It actually causes exocytosis of dopamine vesicles. That is why cocaine is activity dependent as it's mechanism depends on presynaptic activity whereas amphetamine is activity independent.